# PowerShell writes to MSMQ and SSIS reads the message

Tags: node.js, powershell, ssis, msmq

I have to write to the MSMQ from node.js / Powershell.

From node I can use the node-msmq package to write to the local machine but not the the remote machine and also it writes hex values of the message text which is not understood by my end application in SSIS.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui0BR.png)

From powershell, I am able to send messages using the

```
 Send-msmqqueue -Name ".\private$\tcmq" -Label "String Message" -Body "this is a new msg"
```

But this message gets entered in XML format in msmq [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCKkT.png)

When this message is read using ssis message queue task I am getting a random text as follows.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fehmf.png)

I was able to read when I sent from LabVIEW by setting ActiveXMessageFormatter.

Basically, I am able to send and receive from SSIS itself but not from Powershell. I dont know if I have to set any format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So... what do you want to use? Node? Powershell? SSIS? Make up your mind.

Comment: Options 
1. Node writes to MSMQ and SSIS reads from MSMQ
2. Powershell writes to MSMQ and SSIS reads from MSMQ

Comment: Any of the above is fine as I can run ps cmds from node.